# How to extract multiple sequences of bytes from a file with multiple XMLs

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, dll, devexpress

Let's consider a `.dll` file I have. Basically it contains `file.blob`. This file consists of multiple linked pieces of code like this:

```
navbar\groupopenbutton[0].svgï»¿<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" id="Layer_2" tag="Element1">
  <g tag="Element">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="32" height="32" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#AFAFAF" class="Paint" tag="Paint" />
  </g>
</svg>    l  navbar\groupopenbutton_glyph.png‰PNG

   
IHDR   
      u0   gAMA  ±
üa     pHYs  ¼  ¼•¼rI  IDAT8OÝ“;Ja…Ð˜J›X)‰
ðÑˆ… HŠ)æýÀ"E
eÀZ[ÁX‰«Ð
$;ÉFÄ5X™ï2‡iEÈCþó˜ ÷fÜ?#MÓ«<ÏO$˜EÑXÒ¹ªªzq¿$Iòl¡ÑÎ”^-S­Á ¾Á#¾ A°«¸
îtHaFqÎï±ìnP
`,¹ÆÈ²ì^J60­M$+Ër‹-|2»……F;3¦¥ïû}ÕjPÜ#ø‚¿FŠßEQì+nƒÂy†?FÎ²»A¡‚w’k¦Ä$˜×ú³™
ŒÆ2µÐhg¼[Ïó6U«Áf¶  îá“øÀúv·A8„F>¬‘ìnðÈSÞùLòÏàÜ
n
^¨2ñL    IEND®B`‚#
```

This code describes an icon for one of my DevExpress Skins.

As we can see, this is an XML file, plus a chunk of binary data, which is an image. Note that his binary code doesn't belong to any tag, it's just outside the XML structure. This entire piece of code basically says "it is a group open button from navbar, it has a viewbox with particular size, and below is the binary of the icon itself". And this `file.blob` consists of multiple of these chunks, thus becoming tedious to parse and read.

My question is, what is this kind of data storage, how do I read and parse it correctly? Ideally, I would want to have a hashmap of that binary code as a value, and name (navbar\groupopenbutton) as a key. I can't really use regex, because I would have to convert everything to binary, to not lose the data behind those "weird" symbols in binary, and also it would be extremely slow. Any ideas?

Maybe there is something in the `Assembly` class that I could use, or maybe some special `Stream` that can parse this in a refined way?

Thanks.

Comment: You are looking at it backwards.  It is xml data inside binary data.  You have binary data and you need to get the specification for the data to be able to exact properly.

Comment: @jdweng so you assume that `navbar\groupopenbutton[0].svgï»¿` and that big chunk of binary code actually **enclose** that XML piece??

Comment: You have to look at this file using a hex editor or hex viewer. Typically, these kind of formats have a binary length indicator that tell you how many of the following bytes you have to read for the file content. TLV and KLV are similar formats.

Comment: Yes.  The upside down question mark is the start of the xml and there is some invisible character at end of xml.  The only real way of using files like this is to get the specification .

Comment: Looks like a compiled `resx` file